# Send scheduled reminder to group

Tags: activities, groups, scheduled-reminders

I am trying to send an Activity-triggered scheduled reminder to a group. These contacts will not be otherwise associated with the Activity.

Recipients > Send to group doesn't seems to be working and there's something in the documentation that suggests only members of the group that *also* meet some other criteria (Activity associated contacts?) will get the email, but this isn't clear.

So maybe it would work to use the 'Limit or Add Recipients' > 'Also include' option. But this doesn't exist in scheduled reminders *only* for Entity type = Activity.

Thinking about asking someone to write an extension to override this on our site, but want to check there's not some deep reason this is omitted for Activities.

Or maybe it's a bug, and Recipients > Send to group is supposed to work...?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This old topic https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php%3Ftopic=36142.0.html pointed at this https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15536 and to some PRs https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/5477 https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/5421

Comment: Thanks Peter, that's interesting. None of that mentions why that function isn't there for Activities, as that's not the focus of the discussion. The mystery continues. Looks like I'll have to call up DGG :) Or maybe Joanne...

Comment: just for completeness, my other comment in chat was about whether the fact that contacts can be 'connected' to an Activity as any or all of source, with, target might be the factor adding complexity to this situation

Comment: Recipient(s) selector for activity that says "Assignee, Target, Source" uses the same column in database that's used for limit-to / include for other entities. And that's probably the reason why it does not appear separately like for other entities. To provide both the options like "Source" and limit-to/include, it would probably need a new column and code to handle both.

Comment: @DeepakSrivastava in our particular case we actually **only** want to send to a group, not any of the activity contacts. Does that change anything?

Comment: @DeepakSrivastava I've updated my question to explain what I actually want to achieve.

Comment: have you looked at civirules - or if drupal, then drupal rules

Comment: @petednz-fuzion yes. I'm talking to CiviCoop about adding some functionality to CiviRules, and I have it just all got too complicated with Rules - needing to add a rule for each smart group and a View for each one - for the Rule to cycle through the email addresses. I'm hopeful that someone else I'm talking to will be able to write something custom. I'll report back!

Comment: cool. good luck. otherwise give us a ping next week if you want us to take a further look

Comment: @KatyJ If you just want to send it to a group irrespective of Source/Assignee/Target, think it should work as it is. And might be a bug (and possibly easier fix than some new code) if it's not working already.

Comment: @DeepakSrivastava Yep, there's a growing consensus that it's a bug.  Andrew at AGH points out that it probably is a bug but it's so long-standing (since 2014) that we would have trouble getting it changed at this point because people may be relying on the buggy behavior.

Comment: Just discovered this problem for myself when testing, as the email only went to a contact involved in the activity & not to the rest of the group.  That's a real disappointment and it was only this SE question that provided the answer. Scheduled Reminders is sparsely documented and I couldn't find anything about this restriction.  It's a bug in my book.

Comment: @AndyClark We ended up commissioning AGH Strategies to write an extension. 
Check out https://github.com/aghstrategies/com.aghstrategies.activityemail and the readme: https://github.com/aghstrategies/com.aghstrategies.activityemail/blob/master/README.md - helped us out a bunch. Ask if you have any Questions. (yes, it's a bug)

Comment: Many thanks, Katy, that looks good. A pity I can't give you a +1 - maybe you should put that as an answer here?  Thx again!

Comment: ... and most important, it works!

Comment: @AndyClark Good call. I have done.

Answer (score 2):

We ended up commissioning AGH Strategies to write an extension. Check out github.com/aghstrategies/com.aghstrategies.activityemail and the readme: github.com/aghstrategies/com.aghstrategies.activityemail/blob/… - that was the missing piece for us.

Comment: cool. do you understand why in their example the From shows as 1,1

Comment: @petednz-fuzion I think the readme is not quote up to date. It now works with typing in a contact name or email address.

Comment: I've raised an issue with this extension as it seems to limit the number of emails sent to 25 - the 2 groups we're sending to have 45 contacts with primary email addresses- see https://github.com/aghstrategies/com.aghstrategies.activityemail/issues